# Deploy problem in production server related to a .cs file and RequireJS

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I have a project in development using ASP.Net. And have the production server on AWS using Elastic Beanstalk.
The problem is the JS files after requireJS won't load using the helper i made. But on my local PC when i debug it works perfect!.

I added requireJS, configure it and added a helper to locate and use specific JS file according to the View rendered. After publishing the project using Web Deploy Package, I upload and deploy using Elastic Beanstalk in the corresponding Application. It goes well, but when i visit the production site, the JS won't work. The helper is not loading the JS file, but in my debug local PC it does.

This is the footer where i call the method in the helper:

```
@using ypf.Helper

<footer>
...
</footer>

<script src="~/Scripts/dist/require.js"></script>
<script>
    @Html.ViewSpecificRequireJS()
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

This is the helper:
RequireJSHelper.cs

```
using System;
using System.Configuration;
using System.IO;
using System.Text;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Mvc;

namespace ypf.Helper
{
    public static class RequireJsHelpers
    {
        public static MvcHtmlString RequireJs(this HtmlHelper helper, string config, string module)
        {
            var require = new StringBuilder();

            string jsLocation = "/Scripts/";


            if (File.Exists(helper.ViewContext.HttpContext.Server.MapPath(Path.Combine(jsLocation, module + ".js"))))
            {
                require.AppendLine("require( [ \"" + jsLocation + config + "\" ], function() {");
                require.AppendLine("    require( [ \"" + module + "\"] );");
                require.AppendLine("});");
            }

            return new MvcHtmlString(require.ToString());
        }

        public static MvcHtmlString ViewSpecificRequireJS(this HtmlHelper helper)
        {
            var action = helper.ViewContext.RouteData.Values["action"];
            var controller = helper.ViewContext.RouteData.Values["controller"];
            var namespaces = helper.ViewContext.RouteData.DataTokens["namespaces"];

            if (namespaces != null)
            {
                string namespacesToString = ((string[])namespaces)[0].Replace(".", " ");
                string[] namespacesWordList = namespacesToString.Split(' ');
                string namespacesWord1 = ((string[])namespacesWordList)[2];
                string namespacesWord2 = ((string[])namespacesWordList)[3];
                return helper.RequireJs("config.js", string.Format("views/{0}/{1}/{2}/{3}", namespacesWord1, namespacesWord2, controller, action));
            } else
            {
                return helper.RequireJs("config.js", string.Format("views/{0}/{1}", controller, action));
            }
        }
    }

}
```

So i want is this output on production once rendered:

```
</footer>

<script src="/Scripts/dist/require.js"></script>
<script>
    require( [ "/Scripts/config.js" ], function() {
    require( [ "views/Home/Index"] );
});

</script>
```

Instead i get this:

```
</footer>

<script src="/Scripts/dist/require.js"></script>
<script>

</script>
```

## Again, it gives the expected output when debugging locally, but doesn't in the production server once I upload and deploy the .zip using Elastic Beanstalk

**Solution:**

*Let me clarify for those reading this, that this issue was not caused by AWS Beanstalk. It could happen in any cloud service since the problem was in the file I created.*

Thanks to the answer of **@BowB** and **@Abdul**. 
That statement returned false, because the variable `jsLocation = "/Scripts/"` didn't have `~` and when rendered in production it needed the `~` symbol for the server to understand where to find Scripts folder.

So my first try was I added `~` to the value of `jsLocation`, like `jsLocation = "~/Scripts/"`, and then uploaded and deployed again, it worked like a charm, but then when i debugged locally, it wouldn't understand where to find Scripts folder in the RequireJS `require` declaration:
`require(["~/Scripts/config.js"])`

It seems that when you build the deploy package, C# compile and RequireJS understand the `~` symbol in different ways. If the `~` symbol is found in a C# file, it understands is the root where the folder Scripts is, but in RequireJS, it understands other place or wont admit `~`.

So the final solution was i concatenated `"~"` before the variable `jsLocation` in the IF statement:
`if (File.Exists(helper.ViewContext.HttpContext.Server.MapPath(Path.Combine("~" + jsLocation, module + ".js"))))`

Instead of adding it to the value of `jsLocation`

Now it finds the Scripts folder in Debug and in Production. 
For anyone trying to use requireJS in a .Net project that might need this solution.

Comment: Thanks for sharing the link. Though I notice you maybe didn't read the problem, solution through. Since the link is related to a totally different thing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This if statement is returning false in your deploy:

```
if (File.Exists(helper.ViewContext.HttpContext.Server.MapPath(Path.Combine(jsLocation, module + ".js"))))
```

Check that the /Scripts/views/Home/Index.js file is being copied to the correct place in the production deploy configuration. This is likely dependent on the ide you are using.

Comment: GREAT!. Seems the problem is that, let me do a few fixes and will report back. I didn't notice that IF seem to return false. It was always there, just had to read it. Eager to test...

Comment: Your answer pointed straight to the problem. I explain in the edit of my post the solution, for anyone on the same situation.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, It seems to be the file not exists issue, Check the file exists in the location that mentioned in the below code.

```
if (File.Exists(helper.ViewContext.HttpContext.Server.MapPath(Path.Combine(jsLocation, module + ".js"))))
```

Comment: Thanks it was that the issue